# relative url for visualforce render to word

Tags: apex, deployment, dynamic-visualforce, url

Is there a way to make the url used to render images from visualforce to word dynamic. The problem I am facing is that the URL works in sandbox but on deployment I have to change the url for production.

I tried the following suggestion but this didnt work:

```
<apex:image url="{!$Site.CurrentSiteUrl}/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0150Y000000ar3v&oid=00D0Y000000LvL1&lastMod=1513157626000" width="240" height="50"/>
```

Comment: Take a  look at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000097pLIAQ) question from developer forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom formula field for that object.

> Field Name- `Instance_URL`
>
> API Name- `Instance_URL__c`

The return type should be 'Text'.

The formula value should be-

```
LEFT($Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_300, FIND('/services',$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_300))
```

Use in your visualforce with `{!Object_Name.Instance_URL__c}`